# ASP.Net MVC Bundles - Is "MapPathMethod" a valid property of BundleTable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, system.web.optimization

I have found numerous references to "BundleTable.MapPathMethod" in the System.Web.Optimization  namespace.  For instance:

- [unit testing mvc bundles](http://carolynvanslyck.com/techblog/unit_testing_mvc_bundles.html)
- [hidden options of asp net bundling and minification](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2012/09/30/hidden-options-of-asp-net-bundling-and-minification.aspx)

However, I cannot seem to find documentation for "MapPathMethod" anywhere and it does not resolve even though I have the latest version of "Microsoft.ASP.NET Web Optimization Framework" Installed.

Is "MapPathMethod" a valid property of BundleTable?

Comment: the "ignore list" and the "ordering" in the second link is neat, thanks for the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its gone as of version 1.1 as the framework now uses VirtualPathProvider to find files instead, which is also how you can unit test bundling instead of using the old MapPathMethod.